# unexpected EOF while parsing string to float python

Tags: python, csv

I`m trying to read data from CSV file contains matrix of strings
["1", "2", "1", "3", "45", "65"]
I want to change it to float or int to prepare my data to using tensorflow

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tensorFlow
import csv
import ast

file = open('stub.csv')
reader = csv.reader(file)
temp = list(reader)
del temp[0]

# convert data to numpy array
data = np.array([[ast.literal_eval(j) for j in row] for row in temp])
```

when I`m using ast.literal_eval(j) I have got exception:

```
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

I was tying many things, someone can help me please ?

Comment: Why not use `np.loadtxt`

Answer (score 0):

Since you consider your file as a csv, the first value you parse is `["1"` which can't be translated into any python type.

Then, I tried to solve your problem without consider the file as a csv.

```
import numpy as np
import ast

with open('stub.csv') as file:
    temp=file.readlines()

# convert data to numpy array
data = np.array([map(int, ast.literal_eval(row)) for row in temp])
```

You can choose to convert your data to float by replacing `int` by `float`.

Hope this helps.